# Turn by turn Instruction in 100 meters in SKMaps

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, skmaps

I am using Skobbler Maps,

In the skobbler Framework I  get all the instructions

```
-(void)routingService:(SKRoutingService *)routingService didChangeCurrentAdviceInstruction:(NSString *)currentAdviceInstruction nextAdviceInstruction:(NSString *)nextAdviceInstruction
```

In this delegate method getting all the instructions in around 5/10 meters and audio also playing.
How can I customize turn by turn instructions and audio in each 100/200 meters.

[Here the Class Reference](http://developer.skobbler.com/docs/ios/2.1.0/Protocols/SKNavigationDelegate.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do it (yet) as it connected to the routing engine & its settings and one would need to change the configuration file used by the routing engine - since this is currently done at C++ level there is no way for you to change this at SDK (Objective-C or Java) level.

The advices should normally be spaced nicely (it's the same in our navigation consumer apps) with distance - the only exception would be tight turns at high speed.

What routing profile are you using and which is the simulation speed?